# Which statistical test is appropriate?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, binary-data, discrete-data

I have a dataset of two groups, group A and group B, from the same species but different subspecies, each group consisting of 500 members. I've done a study wherein I added members of group A to modified members of group B (study 1), each time individually, so that each member from group A was added to each modified member of group B. Then I repeated this the other way around (study 2), with each member of group B added individually to each individual modified member of group A. For instance, I add A1 to B1, there is a change. I add A1 to B2, there is a change. Then there is no change adding A1 to B3-B500 individually. That gives me a total of 2 changes. I then add up the total amount of changes for all As against all Bs. I then reversed this procedure.

My outcome variable is binary; absence or presence of a change.

What I now want to do, is use statistics to find the probability of the differing results from the two studies being produced by chance if there is no difference in changes produced by the two different subspecies A and B (null hypothesis).

My data is extremely non-normally distributed, with close to 500 changes for each A or B added to the other group, but there is a large difference between the groups (much more changes seen in study 1 than in study 2).

I've tried using the Chi-square test in excel (CHIINV) (since I think it makes no assumptions about the shape of the underlying distribution) which gives me a p < .00001, but this seems erroneous to me, as no matter how small I make my probability cutoff (originally .05, significant even at 1 x 10^-15, which was as low as I was able to go) the result is still significant. I've also played around with invented numbers, and I'm unable to produce insignificant results. My cross tabulations are also peculiar, with expected subtracted from observed being the exact same numbers (though differing in sign) in each column.

I am not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, so any input would be appreciated. I'm thinking I either can't use the Chi-square test for some reason I'm not aware of, that I have too few degrees of freedom (1), or that the samples are correlated in a statistical sense even if not in a research sense. I am sorry if this question is too basic.

Here is my contingency table:

| Observed change | A causes change in B when added to B | B causes change in A when added to A | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | 1470 | 2684 | 5000 |
| Yes | 3530 | 2316 | 5000 |
| Total | 5000 | 5000 | 10000 |

Comment: You are correct that a chi-squared tests strongly rejects the null hypothesis that Yes is equally likely in both columns. A 'causes changes' more readily then B. // I get lost in your explanation (in paragraph starting, "I've tried....") why you think something must be wrong. The effect is just extremely strong: counts 1470 and 2316 are much smaller than 'expected; according to the null hypothesis. // Maybe you can explain in terms of the subject matter (instead of statistical language) why results seem wrong or unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a chi-squared tests strongly rejects the null hypothesis that Yes is equally likely in both columns: `A` 'causes changes' more readily than `B`.

I get lost in your explanation (in paragraph starting, "I've tried....") why you think something must be wrong. All I see is that the effect is just extremely strong: counts 1470 and 2316 are much smaller than 'expected; according to the null hypothesis.

Maybe you can explain in terms of the subject matter (instead of statistical language) why results seem wrong or unexpected. But from what you have shown, I see nothing wrong with your chi-squared test.